# #error "Use this header only with Microsoft Visual C++ compilers" in CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, linux, codeblocks

Need help here... I try to build my program but halfway this error

> ../../gitRepo/recotraffic2.git/include/inttypes.h|33|error: #error "Use this header only with Microsoft Visual C++ compilers!"|

keep on pop up from `inttype.h` file , how I'm going to solve this

Comment: You may try to use <stdint.h> or <cstdint> instead.

Comment: It seems like you have gotten hold of a Visual C++ runtime library header file. You should tell the creator of the git repository that he or she can't just simply include those header files like that. In fact, he or she should not add *any* standard header files to the repository.

Comment: Delete ../../gitRepo/recotraffic2.git/include/inttypes.h

Comment: Thanks @JoachimPileborg it works after i remove the header file from the folder.

Comment: Thanks @immibis too :)